# Python: Search through a list of objects of the same class to determine object.attribute equals some value for any of the objects in the list

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, iteration

Lets say I have a Kmerobj class with attributes: kmer (a string) and locationlist (a list)

```
class Kmerobj(object):

    def __init__(self,kmer,locationlist):
        self.kmer = kmer
        self.locationlist = locationlist
```

Now let's say I have some string and I'm iterating through this string and creating all the substrings of length k and storing them as Kmerobj objects in a list, with the kmer attribute being the substring and the locationlist attribute being a list of the start sites of that substring. I've written a function to do this.

```
def kmerizeseq(sequence,kmer_size):
    kmer_list = []
    sequence = sequence.upper()
    if (kmer_size <= len(sequence) and kmer_size >= 1):
        for start in range(0,len(sequence)-kmer_size+1,1):
            kmerseq = sequence[start:start+kmer_size]
            if all(kmerseq != kmerobj.kmer for kmerobj in kmer_list):
                kmerinst = Kmerobj(kmerseq,[start],list(seq_name))
                kmer_list.append(kmerinst)
            else:
                for kmerobj in kmer_list:
                    if kmerseq == kmerobj.kmer:
                        kmerobj.locationlist.append(start)
    return kmer_list
```

Now this works. If I run the function

```
kmerizeseq('ATCATC',3)
```

I get a list of three objects. The first has kmer attribute 'ATC' and locationlist attribute [0,3]. The second has kmer attribute 'TCA' and locationlist attribute [1]. The third has kmer attribute 'CAT' and locationlist attribute [2].

My question is this: is there any way to achieve the same outcome more efficiently? Currently I'm running through the entire list to determine if any of the objects have the same kmer attribute as the input, then running through the list again to find the object that matches, and modify it.

Is there any way to run through the list, stop if the kmer attribute of the current object matches the input and modify that object, and if no match is found, add the new kmerobj object to the list? Ideally, I only want to have to iterate through the list once.

Comment: Are you familar with [biopython](https://biopython.org/wiki/Seq)

Comment: Somewhat, although only in the capacity of reading in fasta files (or other file-types) and parsing through the data to generate sequence strings. I'll look into it more and see if there is a module that would be beneficial in this case.

Answer (score 0):

> **Question**: is there any way to achieve the same outcome more efficiently?

You need random access to `Kmerobj`, using the `kmer` Sequence as a key.

Consider the following using a `dict`:

```
class Kmerobj2(object):
    def __init__(self, kmer):
        """Parameter 'kmer' is a tuple of (kmer,index), e.g ('ATC', 0)"""
        self.kmer = kmer[0]
        self.loc = [kmer[1]]

    def append(self, kmer):
        self.loc.append(kmer[1])

    def locations(self):
        return len(self.loc)

    def __str__(self):
        return "{} => {} location(s) at {}".format(self.kmer, self.locations(), self.loc)

def kmerizeseq2(sequence, kmer_size):
    l = []
    # Create len(sequence) tuples == (seq, i) with kmer_size in ONE loop
    for i, c in enumerate(sequence):
        l.append((sequence[i:i + kmer_size], i))

    print("[{}]{}".format( len(l), l))
    #>>>[6][('ATC', 0), ('TCA', 1), ('CAT', 2), ('ATC', 3), ('TC', 4), ('C', 5)]

    d = {}
    # Aggregate all equal kmer of len kmer_size
    for kmer in l[:(len(sequence)-kmer_size)+1]:
        # kmer exists ?
        if kmer[0] in d:
            # Append kmer.loc to d[kmer]
            d[kmer[0]].append(kmer)
        else:
            # Create a new Kmerobj
            d[kmer[0]] = Kmerobj2(kmer)
    return d

if __name__ == "__main__":
    d = kmerizeseq2('ATCATC',3)
    print("type:{}, {}".format(type(d), d))
    #>>> type:<class 'dict'>, {'CAT': <__main__.Kmerobj2 object at 0xf70634ec>, 'TCA': <__main__.Kmerobj2 object at 0xf70634cc>, 'ATC': <__main__.Kmerobj2 object at 0xf706348c>}

    for kmer in d:
        print("{}".format(d[kmer]))
```

> **Output**:
>
> ```
> CAT => 1 location(s) at [2]
> TCA => 1 location(s) at [1]
> ATC => 2 location(s) at [0, 3]
> ```

***Tested with Python: 3.4.2***